# How does Android Automotive retrieve obd2 data?

Tags: android, automotive, android-automotive

I just want to comprehend how Android Automotive handles obd2 data. I discovered the following sources where a BluetoothConnection seems to be a part of their OBD2 api - and this confuses me, because why does Android Automotive need a Bluetooth Connection for OBD2, when it should be fully integrated into the car?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/obd2-lib/src/com/android/car/obd2/connections/BluetoothConnection.java?autodive=0%2F%2F

Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: As far as I know, common vehicles only provide an obd2 normed 16 pin socket, where you can get the vehicle diagnostic data with any adapter you like.
e.g by cable, by an adapter that forwards the information via bluetooth etc.

And the point that confuses me is, do Android Automotive additionally need an OBD-2-Bluetooth adapter, which you have to plug into that socket, so it can receive the information? it seems that is the way it works, but it feels weird somehow. isn't it possible to receive this diagnostic data by CAN without any need of additional adapters.

Comment: I'm talking about Android AutoMOTIVE, not Android Auto.

Comment: My apologies. I've added a tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be there. For many reason.
You are right Android Automotive suppose to be Fully integrated to car. but it does not mean What available via OBD2 port will be available in IVI (Android based).
Because All infomation from all ECU are originally available via OBD2 port (send via CAN network)  IVI can only get some of them ... which only need for Infotainment system like:
IgnitionState, GearBox ..vv. But not Diagnostic data from other ECU.

Anyway, OEM can still do it avaiable in IVI also.. but it take more risk(security, safety) and effort.

Comment: maybe you know which data OEM can make available for third party applications?

Comment: This you need to check with their SDK.. As far i know most of OEM using Android as IVI based now still far away from the point that they can have a common Market for application like  google app or Apple Store. As Android Automotive said that all API available via CAR API but it is still very OEM specific.